# Javascript regular expression to strip out content between double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a javascript regex that will remove all content wrapped in quotes(and the qoutes too), in a string that is the outlook format for listing email addresses. Take a look at the sample below, I am a regex tard and really need some help with this one, any help/resources would be appreciated!

```
"Bill'sRestauraunt"BillsRestauraunt@comcast.net,"Rob&amp;Julie"robjules@ntelos.net,"Foo&amp;Bar"foobar@cstone.net
```

Comment: I pluged each of these regex's into an online regex tester(http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and none of them found a match, am I missing something here or is this a more difficult problem then I thought?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming no nested quotes:

```
mystring.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
/(?:"(?:[^"\\]+|\\(?:\\\\)*.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]+|\\(?:\\\\)*.)*')/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex I use to find and decompose the quoted strings within a paragraph. It also isolates several attendant tokens, especially adjacent whitespace. You can string together whichever parts you want.

```
var re = new RegExp(/([^\s\(]?)"(\s*)([^\\]*?(\\.[^\\]*)*)(\s*)("|\n\n)([^\s\)\.\,;]?)/g);
```